# Get InputStream with getAssets()

Tags: java, android, xml, assets, xmlpullparser

Please help whit the priblem:

I need to get InputStream object from xml-file placed in assets-folder.
Here is my code:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("currency.xml");
```

But I have an error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: currency.xml`

Where is my mistake?

Comment: do you have a file named `currency.xml` into `assets/`?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes, currency.xml is placed in assets/. Full path is /app/assets/currency.xml

Comment: clean build and run again .

Comment: @ChetanJoshi Just cleaned and rebuilded project. Error is still there

Comment: Check wiith some other file like any image .

Comment: what does `context.getAssets().list("/")` return?

Comment: Thanks to everybody! Problem solved. First I placed assets-folder in /app/assets/. But changing path to /app/src/main/assets helps.